# Issue of "Next" IMEOption with birthdate picker

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am doing this for signup screen. I am having three fields email, birthdate and password. 
In birthdate edit text I am displaying birthdate picker dialog. I don't want to let user update birthdate by typing. That's why i gave focusable as "false" and clickable as "true".

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/signup_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            style="@style/big_centered_textfield_style"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:hint="Email address 320"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/birthdate"
            style="@style/big_centered_textfield_style"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="@string/birthdate"
            android:inputType="date"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:onClick="birthdateClicked"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" >
        </EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            style="@style/big_centered_textfield_style"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/normal_font" >
        </EditText>

    </LinearLayout>
```

But when user presses "Next" on email edit text, it directly goes to password that is last. It skips second text field.

What should be done in the scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue using this code.

```
realName.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
                birthdate.performClick();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I am simulating click event for birthdate as it will display birthdate picker on "Next" pressed while key board is being displayed for realname field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xml tag `android:nextFocusDown="@id/yourNextElementID"` to achieve this.

In your case something like this in the `email` `EditText` should work:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/birthdate"
```

Check the android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3anextFocusDown) about it.

**Edit:**

Another solution that may work is to do it programmatically. It can ensure you that your object is created and the call to your `onClick` will be correctly made.

```
yourEmailEditText.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.birthdate);
```

Comment: I already tried it but it skips edit text for birthdate. I think it's because i gave focusable "false". When I changed it to true it goes to birthdate edit text but problem is it displays default keyboard and not calling birthdateClicked method that I use to display date picker.